# How to turn an array of strings into a list with an oxford comma using array methods in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

This is for a homework problem, so I tried to work through it as much as I could before coming here for help. I've got it 95% solved, I just can't figure out the syntax of the last bit or what method I should be using if it's different from what I'm doing now. I can't find any solution to this online that isn't actually my classmates' answers and I'm avoiding clicking on those to see how they completed the problem.

I can return the string without formatting if it only has one element, with only the word 'and' when there are two elements, and I can add commas and the word 'and' when there are more than three elements. However, I can't seem to skip adding the last comma when the array has more than three elements.

```
def oxford_comma(array)
    if array.length == 2
        array.join(" and ")
    elsif array.length > 2
        array.insert(-2, "and")
        array[0..-1].join(", ")
    else
        array.join
    end
end
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
         Failure/Error: expect(oxford_comma(["kiwi", "durian", "starfruit", "mangos", "dragon fruits"])).to eq("kiwi, durian, starfruit, mangos, and dragon fruits")

   expected: "kiwi, durian, starfruit, mangos, and dragon fruits"
        got: "kiwi, durian, starfruit, mangos, and, dragon fruits"

   (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have just one element in the array, [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-join) returns the element itself:

```
['a'].join(' and ') #=> "a"
```

So, you could simplify your code prepending `"and "` to the last element when list size is 3 or more or returning `.join(' and ')` if less than 3 elements:

```
def oxford_comma(list)
  return list.join(' and ') if list.size < 3
  list[-1] = "and " + list[-1]
  list.join(', ')
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This way makes sense to me. I'm not quite sure how this line works: `list[-1] = "and " + list[-1]`   But that's okay! Thanks!

Comment: To answer your question, @AmandaTreutler, `list[-1]` refers to the last item. So, the code sets the last item as `"and " + last_item`. After that line, the last item becomes: ` and ITEM`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT with max comments:

You can do that:

```
def oxford_comma(array)
  array = [*array]
  case array.size
  when 0
    ''
  when 1
    array[0].to_s
  when 2
    array.join(' and ')
  else
    array_copy = array
    array_copy[-1] = "and #{array_copy[-1]}"
    array_copy.join(', ')
  end
end
```

The case when is to handle edge cases for empty array, single value array and double values array.
Otherwise, you change the last item to add the `and` then join everything  with comma.
Use a copy of the array to be non destructive.

[image]

Comment: This is not the expected output, you see in OP's post it's `mangos, and dragon fruits`. I think you need to special case when length=2 (just join by "and" without the comma) and have the 'else' case join by ", and"

Comment: additional edge cases you may want to handle: 1) non array argument like nil or single value, use the `array = [*array]` notation 2) array of non string, change for array[0],to_s in the `when 1` block

Comment: tx max, didn't notice that

Comment: Changed with another versio. But the use of a copy is useless since I'd also used the array = [*array] that already made a copy.

Answer (score 0):

For readability, I suggest a straightforward solution.

```
def oxford_comma(arr)
  case arr.size
  when 0
    ""
  when 1
    arr.first
  when 2
    arr.join(' and ')
  else
    [arr[0..-2].join(', '), arr.last].join(', and ')
  end
end
```

```
oxford_comma ["blue", "green", "pink", "white"]
  #=> "blue, green, pink and white" 
oxford_comma ["blue", "green"]
  #=> "blue and green" 
oxford_comma ["blue"]
  #=> "blue" 
oxford_comma []
  #=> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of Ruby that supports [Pattern Matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html) (experimental in 2.7, official in 3.0 I believe), you could do something like this:

```rb
def oxford_comma(array)
  case array
  in [word]
    word
  in [word_1, word_2]
    "#{word_1} and #{word_2}"
  in [*words, last_word]
    "#{words.join(', ')}, and #{last_word}"
  end
end
```

You could add an `in []` case as well if you need to handle an empty array.  You may also want to add an `else` case at the end in case something unexpected gets passed in.